# CListCtrl shows text befor images (text left , image right).how do i align text right and image left?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using list control to view text and images  , every selected item is related to a specific page. but I would like to show image then text , the list is in report view(style) with only FULLROWSELECT extendedstyle,image list contains bitmap images(just for test)  can any one help?

```
    code::
    int fmt_col = LVCFMT_LEFT;
if( MCCObject::IsLanguageRTL())
    fmt_col = LVCFMT_RIGHT;
//c_MainList.ModifyStyle(LVS_ICON | LVS_LIST | LVS_REPORT, 0);
//c_MainList.ModifyStyle( 0, LVS_REPORT);
DWORD style = LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT  ;
c_MainList.SetExtendedStyle( style);
c_MainList.InsertColumn(0, _T("Item Name"), fmt_col);


CRect rect;
c_MainList.GetClientRect(&rect);
int nColInterval = rect.Width() - 5;
c_MainList.SetColumnWidth(0,nColInterval);
CImageList *pImageList;
pImageList = new CImageList();
pImageList->Create( 32, 32, ILC_MASK | ILC_COLOR16,2, 2);
 //pImageList->Create( 40, 40, ILC_MASK | ILC_COLOR16, 2, 1);

CBitmap bitmap;


bitmap.LoadBitmap(  IDB_HRBITMAP32);
pImageList->Add( &bitmap, (COLORREF)0xFFFFFF);
bitmap.DeleteObject();

bitmap.LoadBitmap( IDB_HRBITMAP33);
pImageList->Add( &bitmap, (COLORREF)0xFFFFFF);
bitmap.DeleteObject();
c_MainList.SetImageList( pImageList, LVSIL_SMALL);

COLORREF col;
col = RGB(240,240,240);
c_MainList.SetBkColor(col);
c_MainList.SetTextBkColor(col);
c_MainList.SetRedraw(TRUE);

    CString item_str = _T("");
int i = 0;
LVITEM lvi;
CString strItem;

lvi.mask =    LVIF_TEXT|LVIF_IMAGE;
lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
lvi.iIndent = 2;
item_str = MCCObject::GetResourceString(IDS_EMPINFO);
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR) item_str;
lvi.iImage = 1;     // There are 8 images in the image list
c_MainList.InsertItem( &lvi);
//c_MainList.SetItem(&lvi);
//c_MainList.SetItemData( 0, (DWORD_PTR)0);

i++;
lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
item_str = MCCObject::GetResourceString(IDS_EMPDOC);
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)  item_str;
lvi.iImage = 1;     // There are 8 images in the image list
c_MainList.InsertItem(&lvi);
//c_MainList.SetItemData( 1, (DWORD_PTR)1);
i++;
lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
item_str = MCCObject::GetResourceString(IDS_OFFICIALDETAILS);
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR) item_str;
lvi.iImage = 1;     // There are 8 images in the image list
c_MainList.InsertItem(&lvi);
    //c_MainList.SetItemData( 2, (DWORD_PTR)2);
i++;
lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
item_str = MCCObject::GetResourceString(IDS_EMPSALARY);
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR) item_str;
lvi.iImage = 1;     // There are 8 images in the image list
c_MainList.InsertItem(&lvi);
//c_MainList.SetItemData( 3, (DWORD_PTR)3);
i++;
lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
item_str = MCCObject::GetResourceString(IDS_WORKPERIODS);
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR) item_str;
lvi.iImage = 1;     // There are 8 images in the image list
c_MainList.InsertItem(&lvi);
//c_MainList.SetItemData( 4, (DWORD_PTR)4); 
i++;
lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = i;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
item_str = MCCObject::GetResourceString(IDS_EMPTIMESYS);
lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR) item_str;
lvi.iImage = 1;     // There are 8 images in the image list
c_MainList.InsertItem(&lvi);
```

Comment: what if you add a second column and add the image there?

Comment: c_MainList.ModifyStyleEx( WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING, WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING | WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL);

Comment: applying that style I am getting the column header on the left and the content on the right, LOL